# Why JobScheduler starting immediately?

Tags: java, notifications, android-jobscheduler

I have an code for `JobScheduler` which running after clicking button:

```
 ComponentName serviceName = new ComponentName(v.getContext(), TestJobService.class);
 JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, serviceName)
         .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
         .setRequiresCharging(false)
         .setPeriodic(900000)
         .setBackoffCriteria(10000, JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
         .setPersisted(true)
         .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
         .build();

 JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
 scheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
```

And I have a task in `TestJobService extends JobService` for show `Notification`:

```
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

    Intent test = new Intent(this, Diarys.class);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Nilesh_channel";
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("test text")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logonotification)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(test);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    mNotificationManager.notify(1000, notificationBuilder.build());
    return false;
}
```

And when I click on button for run `JobScheduler`-code, `Notification` showing immediately, not after 900000 ms (15 min).

**How can I run job after 15 minutes after clicking button?**

Comment: `900000` is hard to read, and even when you’ve counted the digits, it’s not obvious that it equals 15 minutes. I suggest `TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code from this ->

```
ComponentName serviceName = new ComponentName(v.getContext(), TestJobService.class);
                    JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, serviceName)
                            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
                            .setRequiresCharging(false)
                            .setPeriodic(900000)
                            .setBackoffCriteria(10000, JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
                            .setPersisted(true)
                            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
                            .build();
```

to this ->

```
ComponentName serviceName = new ComponentName(v.getContext(), TestJobService.class);
                    JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, serviceName)
                            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
                            .setRequiresCharging(false)
                            .setPeriodic(900000,900000)
                            .setBackoffCriteria(10000, JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
                            .setPersisted(true)
                            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
                            .build();
```

because of flex period, which will start execution after some time. in our case 15 min -> 15 * 60 * 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the android development pages:

> Specify that this job should recur with the provided interval, not more than once per period. You have no control over when within this interval this job will be executed, only the guarantee that it will be executed at most once within this interval.

Using setPeriodic with the second argument allows for flex, which will execute within the flex period from the end of the period.

> Specify that this job should recur with the provided interval and flex. The job can execute at any time in a window of flex length at the end of the period.